# $SU(2)$ with non-standard matter Supersymmetry

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry, higgs, quantum-chromodynamics

Consider the theory with 1 chiral multiplet $Φ$ of isospin 1 and 2 chiral multiplets $^I$ of isospin 1/2. The superpotential is $ = 0$.

I found the dimension of the moduli space as 4 by the Higgs Mechanism. (dim M= No. of Chiral multiplets - No. of vector multiplets= 2$N_C$ + $N_C^2$-1 - ($N_C^2$-1)= 4 where $N_C$=2 is the number of colours)

I was wondering what are the gauge invariant operators in this theory and how many are there, and if they satisfy any relations?
I could only think of $\epsilon^{a_1a_2}Q^I_{a_1}Q^J_{a_2}$ but there should be at least 4.